# Windows: Getting glyph outlines for substitution characters from other fonts

Tags: windows, fonts, gdi+, truetype, glyph

I need to render fonts into a 3d game world, so I use the GetGlyphOutline outline function to get the glyph shapes to render into a texture. However, I want to be able to handle the case where characters are not present in the given font (as is often the case for asian other other international text). Windows text rendering will automatically substitute fonts which have the needed characters. But GetGlyphOutline will not. How can I detect this case, and get the outlines for the substituted glyphs? Mac OS X Core Text has a function to get a matching substitution font for a given font and a string - is there anything similar on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out what I needed to know myself: The [IMLangFontLink interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741048(VS.85).aspx), especially the MapFont method contain the needed functionality to find out which substitution fonts should be used on windows.

Comment: Is the IMLangFontLink interface library always installed on windows?

Comment: As far as i could tell, it gets installed by Internet Explorer 4.0 or higher. I don't know if it's safe to presume that it is on any windows system, even if IE has been removed or not.

Answer (score 1):

I too have puzzled with `GetGlyphOutline`. I'm not sure if you were able to do the same, but I was able to get mixed-script text outlines by using `TextOut()` in combination with `BeginPath()`, `EndPath()` and `GetPath()`.

For example, even with the Arial font, I am able to get the path of the Japanese text 「テスト」 (using C++, but can easily be done in C as well):

```
SelectObject(hdc, hArialFont);
BeginPath(hdc);
TextOut(hdc, 100, 100, L"\u30c6\u30b9\u30c8"); // auto font subbing
EndPath(hdc);

// get number of points in path
int pc = GetPath(hdc, NULL, NULL, 0);

if (pc > 0)
{
    std::vector<POINT> points(pc);
    std::vector<BYTE> types(pc); // PT_MOVETO, PT_LINETO, PT_BEZIERTO

    GetPath(hdc, &points[0], &types[0], pc);

    // it seems the first four points are the bounding rect
    // subsequent points match up to their types

    for (int i = 4; i < pc; i++)
    {
        if (types[i] == PT_LINETO)
            LineTo(hdc, points[i].x, points[i].y); // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may work, doesn't using LineTo to render the fonts only get you a font outline? Also you won't get Anti-Aliasing, and will it properly handle bezier curves in TTF Fonts?

Comment: @jonas: It all depends on the device context you are drawing on (and how it is configured). Also if you use `LineTo` within `BeginPath` and `EndPath` then nothing is drawn until you use `StrokePath` or `EndPath`. Also this was just demonstrating that you could obtain the path, once you have the path you can extrude it into a 3D object or draw it on the screen.